# How to Add or Change Post Title

Tags: sql, title

How to add post titles with new titles via sql?
example post title now "beddu". i want to adding/ change "Add beddu"
thank before

Comment: Use [wp_update_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do will be find the post you want to modify. To find the post named "beddu" which `post_type` is `post`, you can excute this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post'
  AND post_title = 'beddu';
```

After you test and find the condition is correct. Move to update part.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_title = 'Add beddu'
WHERE post_type = 'post'
  AND post_title = 'beddu';
```

Remember to change `wp_posts` to your corresponding table name.

Comment: Thanks for U attention... How do I change that for all post titles. Add titles at the beginning. Because my post title name is not just "beddu"

Comment: For all posts, you just need to remove `AND post_title = 'beddu'` from the SQL command

Comment: Be sure to always backup your database.